# LINQ Conditional Composite key in INNER JOIN

Tags: c#, linq, join, linq-to-entities, inner-join

Let's say I have an Order and OrderDetails collections. How can I write following sql in LINQ (query or fluent syntax)?

> select top 1 OD.ProductId
>   from Order O
>   inner join OrderDetail OD on OD.OrderID = 1
>    and OD.OrderId = O.OrderId
>    **and ((OD.OrderDate = O.OrderDate) or (OD.OrderDate is null))**
>   where O.CustomerId = 2
>   order by OD.OrderDate desc

I know that I can create an anonymous type containing all the columns to match for join however how can I write conditional logic for inner join as mentioned above in **BOLD**

Comment: It doesn't have to be part of the join. You can write a simple Where.

Comment: Hi Gert thanks. Can you provide a sample code please?

Comment: @SyedDanish: This should be a trivial query conversion, so it's difficult to know what you're having a hard time with. Can you show us the LINQ code you've already written, and which specific part you're having difficulty with?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, I was basically asking if a "conditional" comparison for "composite keys" in a linq join is possible? 
May be the example I posted is not good for that purpose and it can be re-written in Linq without using a join however I will update my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query will give the same results as:

```
select top 1 OD.ProductId
from Order O
inner join OrderDetail OD
  on OD.OrderId = O.OrderId
where O.CustomerId = 2
  and OD.OrderID=1
  and (OD.OrderDate is null or OD.OrderDate=O.OrderDate)
order by OD.OrderDate desc
```

You should be able to convert that to LINQ much easier.

```
var results=db.OrderDetail
  .Where(od=>od.Order.CustomerId==2)
  .Where(od=>od.OrderId==1)
  .Where(od=>od.OrderDate==null || od.OrderDate==od.Order.OrderDate)
  .OrderBy(od=>od.OrderDate)
  .Select(od=>od.ProductId)
  .First();
```

You can further simplify that to:

```
var results=db.OrderDetail
  .Where(od=>od.Order.CustomerId==2 &&
    (od.OrderId==1) &&
    (od.OrderDate==null || od.OrderDate==od.Order.OrderDate))
  .OrderBy(od=>od.OrderDate)
  .Select(od=>od.ProductId)
  .First();
```

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks. I am accepting your answer as it's correct for the scenario I mentioned however I am still interested to know how can we write LINQ equivalent for situations where conditional logic is part of "Join" condition and cannot be written in "Where" clause. probably I should ask a different question with a specific code sample.

Comment: @SyedDanish I think you'll find it hard to find an example like that, however, an alternative is to Union two separate queries together each with one part of the "or".