# Join on a conditional composite key with Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

So I have two tables I need to join based on 4 different Id fields. In the first table, 3 of the ids are required, where the 4th is optional. They represent an organization, a department, a position, and an optional unit within the position which i will call opUnit. On the second Table, I have 4 different id fields that are all nullable. They function as an assignment to a particular group of org/dep/pos/opUnit. If any of those fields are null, then we can assume that it is meant to match on all of that unit. For instance, an org id of 3 and a dep id of 24, followed by a null pos and null opUnit id would mean that this particular assignment belongs to all positions within the org with id 3 and the department of id 24.

That said I need to perform a join.

what I initially had looks something like this

```
from user in listOfUsers
join odp in this.DBContext.odpOpUnitTable on user.positionFieldId equals odp.userPositionFieldId //each user has an odp/opUnit, so join from users
from minReq in this.DBContext.ODPRequirementTable.Where(req => (!req.UseOrganization || odp.OrganizationId == req.OrganizationId)
                                                                                            && (!req.UseDepartment || odp.DepartmentId == req.DepartmentId)
                                                                                            && (!req.UsePosition || odp.PositionId == req.PositionId)
                                                                                            && (!req.UseOpUnit || odp.OpUnitId == req.OpUnitId)).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

The "Use___" fields are just helper fields that indicate that the corresponding Id is null and is not use to filter down org/dep/pos/opUnit. That from statement does what I need it to do, but it is unacceptably slow. What I would like to do is something like the following

```
from user in listOfUsers
join odp in this.DBContext.odpOpUnitTable on user.positionFieldId equals odp.userPositionFieldId //each user has an odp/opUnit, so join from users
join minReq in this.DBContext.ODPRequirementTable on new { orgId = odp.OrganizationId, depId = odp.DepartmentId, posId = odp.PositionId, opId = odp.OpUnitId }
                                                                          equals new { orgId = minReq.UseOrganization ? minReq.OrganizationId : odp.OrganizationId
                                                                                       depId = minReq.UseDepartment ? minReq.DepartmentId : odp.DepartmentId
                                                                                       posId = minReq.UsePosition ? minReq.PositionId : odp.PositionId
                                                                                       opId = minReq.UseOpUnit ? minReq.OpUnitId : odp.OpUnitId
                                                                                     }
```

essentially, only using fields that aren't null to perform the join. This particular example doesn't work though as it uses fields from the left side of the equation in the right side.

My question is essentially listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418771/linq-conditional-composite-key-in-inner-join) but the accepted solution was "use a where clause instead", but a where clause doesn't work in my case due to how long it takes. Alternatively, someone mentioned using a union on the different OR cases in the join, but that would be a union per permutation of every id being null which would be like 16 unions or something like that, so that's not acceptable either.

I don't know if it's possible to do this, but I haven't been able to find any questions like this, so hopefully this is a useful question to have asked.

EDIT: Just to clarify I understand how to do this in SQL, but I want to know if there is a LINQ way to do this without sacrificing performance.

Comment: Why does it look like you are joining 3 tables when you just discuss joining two?

Comment: What is `aodp` in your sample of what you would like to do?

Comment: When I initially posted the code samples, I removed some app specific conventions to focus the problem, but in the second example i forgot to make the same changes i made to the first. I updated it to make both examples use the same variables

Comment: As for the 3 tables, i use a list of users to get the list of their org/dep/pos, but it's not important to the join in question (i.e. odpOpUnitTable to ODPRequirementTable). Im aware this may return duplicates if a user has multiple org/dep/pos entries, but I'm hoping it's not important with regards to the question.

Comment: Do you have a way to do this efficiently in SQL?

Comment: Yeah, I could easily do it in a proc, and that will likely what i will do regardless of the answer, but i want to see if i can get a solid answer on what the "Linq way" to solve this problem is. So far, that answer I linked was the only answer to this question i've seen and it only circumvented the answer I want to hear by changing the code to support an easier answer.

Essentially in the proc, I will be selecting from a 4 way union where odpOpUnitTable and ODPRequirementTable are joined 4 times on each of the parameters in the composite key on the second example

Comment: to elaborate, the 4 conditions would be essentially "Match at least on ___" where ___ is each of the 4 fields. UseOrganization AND organization matches, followed !UseDepartement OR department matches, !UsePosition OR position matches, etc. Then repeat for each field, swapping out the "Match at least on " case for each one

Comment: And that wouldn't be as slow as the where?

Comment: Historically, no. In our app, we've done the same logic elsewhere in procs and it consistently runs in subsecond, where this where clause is taking upwards of 30 for like a dozen users. There are a massive amount of fields in each table as well and each user may have multiple positions. I'm no expert on SQL optimization, but I do know that the SQL that LINQ spits out is sometimes very roundabout and unoptimized, relying on users setting up their queries in very specific ways in order to avoid pitfalls. My question here was written with those pitfalls in mind while looking to avoid them.

Comment: I guess what I'm hoping for in an answer to this is how this situation is best solved with LINQ and also with performance in mind. I've seen multiple answer to this question, but they all fail at least one of those two criteria, and as such I would consider them reworking the criteria rather than providing the best solution to that criteria.